# Generate every permutation with unique restrictions

Tags: python, optimization, generator, permutation

I'm trying to create a testing script that will generate every possible permutation of values according to multiple lists. However, there are some restrictions on which values can be matched with others. Thus far, I've come up with the following:

```py
fieldTypes = ['Text', 'Float', 'Double', 'Short', 'Long', 'Date']
domainTypes = ['Coded', 'Range']
rangeSplitPolicies = ['Default', 'Duplicate', 'Geometry_Ratio']
rangeMergePolicies = ['Default', 'Area_Weighted', 'Sum_Values']
codedSplitPolicies = ['Default', 'Duplicate']
codedMergePolicies = ['Default']

for fieldType in fieldTypes:
    for domainType in domainTypes:
        # Skip incompatible domainType-fieldType permutations
        if domainType == 'Coded' and fieldType == 'Date' \
        or domainType == 'Range' and fieldType == 'Text':
           break

        # Range domain-type handling
        if domainType == 'Range':
            for splitPolicy in rangeSplitPolicies:
                # Date fields require special handling and only support the 
                # the default keyword for their split and merge policies
                if fieldType == 'Date':
                    permutation = '{0}-{1}'.format(
                        fieldType,
                        domainType,
                        'Default',
                        'Default')
                else:
                    for mergePolicy in rangeMergePolicies:
                        permutation = '{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}'.format(
                            fieldType,
                            domainType,
                            splitPolicy,
                            mergePolicy)

        # Coded-value domain-type handling
        else:
            for splitPolicy in codedSplitPolicies:
                for mergePolicy in codedMergePolicies:
                    permutation = '{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}'.format(
                        fieldType,
                        domainType,
                        splitPolicy,
                        mergePolicy)

        # Do more stuff...
```

Obviously, this is not very elegant. If possible, I'd like to use a Generator since I'll only need to get each permutation once, but I'm really not sure what the best way is to organize this and get every possible permutation of field and domainType as well as the appropriate split and merge policies for each domainType while enforcing nuanced restrictions of:

- Coded Value based Domains are not supported on Date Fields
- Range based Domains are not supported on Text Fields
- Date Fields only support the 'Default' keyword for their Split and Merge policy.

I'm just getting permutation as a string for now, but it could be returned as a tuple, list or anything that is easily parseable.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: Can you show some input output pairs?

Comment: @BallpointBen do you mean what the expected return values might be? right now its not setup as a function, so I'm confused by what you mean by input output pairs

Comment: It might be a problem that you `break` the inner loop and not `continue` with the next iteration. So replace `break` with `continue"`... Also you maybe should use paranthesis around the AND-operations. `(dt == "..." and ft = "...") or (...)`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you really mean permutations, but Cartesian product.

Consider doing something like the following:

```
def gen(domain_types, field_types):
    for d, f in itertools.product(domain_types, field_types):
        if is_okay(d, f):
            yield d, f
```

I know you have a more fields to worry about, but this example should suffice.